# Optimization of average calculation from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of dictionaries, with keys 'a', 'n', 'o', 'u'.
Is there a way to speed up this calculation, for instance with [NumPy](https://numpy.org/)? There are tens of thousands of items in the list.

The data is drawn from a database, so I must live with that it's in the form of a list of dictionaries originally.

```
x = n = o = u = 0
for entry in indata:
    x += (entry['a']) * entry['n']  # n - number of data points
    n += entry['n']
    o += entry['o']
    u += entry['u']

    loops += 1

average = int(round(x / n)), n, o, u
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? What's the surrounding code? Context helps.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, updated question slightly.

Comment: You might be able to optimize a bit with `operator.itemgetter`

Comment: Maybe your database can sum the values.

Comment: @mgilson, write up an example of how to do that and you have yourself an upvote. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this will be much faster, but I suppose it's a candidate for `timeit`...

```
from operator import itemgetter
x = n = o = u = 0
items = itemgetter('a','n','o','u')
for entry in indata:
    A,N,O,U = items(entry)
    x += A*N  # n - number of data points
    n += N
    o += O    #don't know what you're doing with O or U, but I'll leave them
    u += U

average = int(round(x / n)), n, o, u
```

At the very least, it saves a lookup of `entry['n']` since I've now saved it to a variable

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant -- I just thought it was cool when I could `itemgetter` multiple things from a `dict` at once.  I've never done that before -- figured I'd share.  At some point, maybe I'll do a quick `timeit` test to see how it performs ...

Comment: Yes. BTW, I profiled your code on my data, seems like about 10% faster. :-)

Comment: Looks prettier now I think, so I will use your version. A little faster AND prettier is a net win.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
mean_a = np.sum(np.array([d['a'] for d in data]) * np.array([d['n'] for d in data])) / len(data)
```

### EDIT: Actually, the method above from @mgilson is faster:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
from pandas import *
```

data=[]
for i in range(100000):
    data.append({'a':np.random.random(), 'n':np.random.random(), 'o':np.random.random(), 'u':np.random.random()})

def func1(data):
    x = n = o = u = 0
    items = itemgetter('a','n','o','u')
    for entry in data:
        A,N,O,U = items(entry)
        x += A*N  # n - number of data points
        n += N
        o += O    #don't know what you're doing with O or U, but I'll leave them
        u += U

```
    average = int(round(x / n)), n, o, u
    return average
```

def func2(data):
    mean_a = np.sum(np.array([d['a'] for d in data]) * np.array([d['n'] for d in data])/len(data)
    return (mean_a, 
                np.sum([d['n'] for d in data]), 
                np.sum([d['o'] for d in data]), 
                np.sum([d['u'] for d in data])
               )

def func3(data):
    dframe = DataFrame(data)
    return np.sum((dframe["a"]*dframe["n"])) / dframe.shape[0], np.sum(dframe["n"]), np.sum(dframe["o"]), np.sum(dframe["u"])

In [3]: %timeit func1(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.6 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit func2(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit func3(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 129 ms per loop

If you are doing other operations on the data, I would definitely look into using the Pandas package. It's DataFrame object is a nice match to the list of dictionaries that you are working with. I think that the majority of the overhead is IO operations of getting the data into numpy arrays or DataFrame objects.

Comment: I can't believe `itemgetter` beats numpy.  I suppose the bottleneck here really is getting the data out of the dictionary and into a form that `numpy` likes.

Comment: Yup. I was shocked. I think its definitely IO getting into numpy arrays that is causing the bottleneck.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use the term `IO` here, but you're right.  (I generally think of IO as reading/writing to disk -- But you've built the list ahead of time).

Comment: @mgilson, maybe call it "memory bottleneck" or something

Answer (score 0):

if all you're looking to do is get an average value on something why not

```
sum_for_average = math.fsum(your_item)
average_of_list = sum_for_average / len(your_item)
```

no mucking about with numpy at all.

Comment: How do I convert the list of dictionaries into "your_list" ?

Comment: used 'your list' as a general placeholder text. if you've got a dictionary entry that's a set of numbers there's several functions in the math module that should do some good for you.